# If statement inside checked attribute of input element in freemarker?

Tags: freemarker

Is it possible to write this in freemarker.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="Available ?" checked="<#if ${status}=='Available'>true<#else>false</#if>"/>
```

For now it throws exception

I want html checkbox to be checked if `status` property equals to `"Available"`.

How to do this in freemarker?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`<#if ${status}=='Available'>` has a syntactical error (that the error message that you haven't included points to, I'm certain): you can't use `${...}` inside FreeMarker tags (well, except inside string literals, but whatever). It should be just `<#if status == 'Available'>`. But, the simples solution for what you want is:

```
checked="${(status == 'Available')?c}"
```

or if you have an older FreeMarker then:

```
checked="${(status == 'Available')?string('true', 'false')}"
```

Comment: Where do I have to declare the 'status' property ?